# Windows 10 Generic / Raw printing of PDF document?

Tags: windows, drivers, printing, printer, network-printer

What I need is to send a PDF document directly to the remote network printer, without any changes, `as it is`, using `Print` button.

In Ubuntu I just use `Generic / Raw Queue` driver, and all is OK.

Problem with Windows 10 is that I can't find a `Generic / Raw Queue` driver, it's only a `Generic / Text only` driver here, and it fails to print PDF.

I tried to use `Microsoft / PDF to file` driver, but it changes PDF (changes PDF structure, it replaces all with 1 image, that I don't need).

Any advices? Or maybe someone could send me a driver that wouldn't change the file and just resend it?

Comment: Can you specify more information about the remote network printer (_virtual printer_)?

Answer (score 4):

If your printer understands PDF directly (most printers require some utility), you  can try sending it to the printer using the following command:

> LPR -S printer_IP_address -P queue_name filename.PDF

The queue_name parameter is printer specific. You could try PDF or RAW. If those don't work, you'll need to look up the printer's documentation.

Here's a user-friendly solution if you don't want to type commands. Use Notepad to create a file containing the command

> LPR -S printer_IP_address -P queue_name %1%

Name this file PrintPDF.bat and place it (or a link to it) on the desktop. From Windows Explorer you can now drag a PDF onto this icon, and it will be sent to the printer.

Comment: thank you for reply! Your advice is working, printer received file, file is good. BUT, i need user-friendly solution, so main idea to do it using usual printing process

Comment: There is no Windows driver that will just send the file "as-is". To "print" it you first have to open it (e.g. using Acrobat). From there you can print it using the normal driver. You could also put the command in a batch file, and then drop the PDF onto the icon for the batch file. In that case, replace filename.PDF with %1%

Comment: Is my suggestion of a desktop icon suitable for what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to set up an LPR/LPD Printer on Windows 10.

**Install the Windows Components**

- Click on the Start button, then **Control Panel**
- Click on **Programs and Features** then click **Turn Windows features on or off, from the left sidebar
- Expand **Print and Document Services**, and make sure the boxes next to **LPD Print Service** and **LPR Port Monitor** are checked
- Click OK and follow the on screen instructions until the components are installed.

[image: image1]

**Create the printer**

- Start **Advanced Printer Setup**
- Click **The printer that I want isn't listed**
- Check **Add a local printer or network printer with manual settings**
- Click **Next**
- Check **Create New Port**
- In the drop-down list choose **Standard TCP/IP Port**
- Click **Next**
- Enter the IP address
- *Uncheck* **Query the printer and automatically select the driver to use**
- Click **Next**
- Leave Standard **Generic Network Card** for Device Type and click **Next**

[image: image2]

- Select **Generic** for Manufacturer and select **Generic/Text Only** for printer type then click **Next**

[image: image3]

- Type the name of the Printer
- Click **Finish** to add the printer

[source](https://www.blackice.com/Help/Internet/BILPDManager/WebHelp/How_to_set_up_LPR_LPD_Printer_on_Windows_10_and_Windows_Server_2016.htm)

Comment: Main question is - i need a driver that would pass file "as is" to the printer. "Query the printer..." option wouldnt work, because i have virtual printer

Comment: I said to *uncheck* this option.

Comment: @harrymc even if you uncheck the port query, you still have to select a printer model. In other words, the driver will still process the PDF before it sends it to the printer.

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the printer model. I added above the procedure as I saw on my computer.

Comment: @harrymc It's the procedure to install a driver, NOT to send files directly to a printer.

Comment: I think I understand why the procedure didn't work for you. See above.

Comment: In case of a problem, please report. This works much better than downvoting.

Comment: The Generic/Text Only driver will NOT send a PDF to the printer. It will convert it to text only, and ignore all non-text objects in the PDF.

Comment: @hdhondt: A PDF file *is* a text file.

Comment: @harrymc Try opening one in Notepad. A PDF is like a binary PostScript file. And, even if it were a text file, it would still be interpreted by the Generic/Text Only driver, rather than being sent to the printer "as is".

Comment: @hdhondt: Did you try it, or are you talking from theory only?

Comment: @harrymc i tried, PDF files are usually like a binary files. Your solution wouldnt work for such PDFs

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is to send a PDF document directly to the remote network printer, without any changes,  as it is, using Print button.

For most apps, this isn't possible using the "Print" button because the application you're using is trying to talk to a non-raw printer driver whereas you explicitely want to bypass those capabilities.  Instead, you should send the raw stream to the printer directly.  To achieve this in Windows (**WITHOUT** the use of a print button)

1. Share the printer on the network.
2. From `cmd` (or PowerShell, etc): `echo sample.pdf > \\computer\printer`

Or from a programming language such as [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript):

```
"use strict";
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
fso.CopyFile("sample.pdf", "\\\\computer\\printer", true);
```

Getting an application to behave this way is not going to be common.  Most applications capable of opening and rendering a PDF wouldn't have the ability to bypass the driver.  This is by convention only.  The underlying languages (e.g. C++, Java) do have techniques for raw data flavors, it's just not something that's commonly associated with the "Print" button you are describing.

> In Ubuntu I just use `Generic / Raw Queue driver`, and all is OK.

Which application inside the Ubuntu operating system allows this?  Generally speaking CUPS will use Ghostscript and and will suffer a similar translation as the Microsoft PDF driver.  I would challenge the claim that the PDF data being sent is "unmodified" on Ubuntu.  It is more likely that is IS modified, but that the modified version is simply more desirable.  If you're right and the byte stream is unmodified, this seems more like a hidden feature of CUPS rather than a problem with WinSpool.